# Elasticsearch Validation Failed

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I created the following map like so

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/movies -d '
{
 "mappings" : {
  "_default_" : {
   "properties" : {
    "title" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
    "director" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
    "year" : { "type" : "integer" }
   }
  }
 }
}
';
```

I have file called others2.json with the contents

```
{"index":{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":1}}
{"title": "Movie1","director": "director1","year": 1962}
```

with an extra line in the end.

When I try to added the contents of other2.json with the line `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @other2.json` I get the following error message

```
{"error":"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;]","status":500}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Added `\n` at the end of all lines. This fixed it.